# I want checkboxes be saved after reload or back on that page again

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

This code below select only one by one checkbox, how can I transform this code so I can select all checkboxes by one click, but I need my variables to stay defined.

```
        $('.checktip').click(function () {
        var iduser = $('.iduser').val();
        var idtip = $(this).attr('idtip');
        var che = $(this).prop('checked');
        $.ajax({
            url: UrlSettingsDocument.OrgUnits,
            data: { iduser: iduser, idtip: idtip, che: che },
            type: "POST",
            success: function (result) {
            if (result.result == "Redirect") {
            window.location = result.url;
     }
     }
    });
    });
```

I using this variables for controller where I save this values in database when I check them or unchecked.

Here is my html code

```
        <input type="hidden" value="@ViewBag.iduser" id="iduser" />
        <hr />
        <table class="table table-striped grid-table">
        <tr>
            <th>Samp</th>
            <th>Id of Book</th>
            <th>
            //Checkbox for check all *(NOT IMPLEMENTED)*
              <input type="checkbox"  id="box" name="checkAll" />
            </th>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var item in (IEnumerable<cit.Models.getCheIdTip_Result>)Model)
        {
         <tr>
          <td>@item.idtip</td>
          <td>@item.tipname</td>
          <td>

         @*@Html.CheckBox(item.id.ToString(), item.iduser == ViewBag.iduser ? true : false, new { idtip = item.idtip, @class = "checktip" })*@

         <div class="pure-checkbox">
         <input type="checkbox" idtip="@item.idtip" class="checktip" checked="@(item.iduser == ViewBag.iduser ? true : false)" name="@item.id.ToString()" id="@item.id.ToString()" />
        <label for="@item.id.ToString()"></label>
        </div>
        </td>
        </tr>
        }
    </table>
```

Comment: add your html as well for a clearer picture.

Comment: @AndrewLohr here is my code